# Trying to make an image move randomly but it's not moving

Tags: java

I'm trying to make an image move randomly but it's not working for some reason. The image appears in the panel but it's not moving. I'm using tow classes for this: a main class and a sub class. This is the code for my sub class.

```
public Image()
{

    randomPosition();

    try {
    image = ImageIO.read(new File("image.png"));

    } catch (IOException e) {}


}


public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawImage(image, x, y, this);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    g.dispose();    
}



public void move()
{


    x += dx;
    y += dy;


    if (x >= 550) {
        x = 550;
        randomDirection();
      }
      if (x <= 1) {
        x = 1;
        randomDirection();
      }
      if (y >= 350) {
        y = 350;
        randomDirection();
      }
      if (y <= 1) {
        y = 1;
        randomDirection();
      }
}

public void randomDirection() {
    double speed = 2.0;
    double direction = Math.random()*2*Math.PI;
    dx = (int) (speed * Math.cos(direction));
    dy = (int) (speed * Math.sin(direction));
    }


public void randomPosition()
{
    x = LEFT_WALL + (int) (Math.random() * (RIGHT_WALL - LEFT_WALL));
    y = UP_WALL + (int) (Math.random() * (DOWN_WALL - UP_WALL));
}

public void run()
{

    long beforeTime, timeDiff, sleep;
    beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (true)
    {
        move();
        repaint();

        timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beforeTime;
        sleep = DELAY - timeDiff;

        if (sleep > 2)
        {
            sleep = 1;
        }
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(sleep);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.out.println("interrupted");
        }

        beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

and this is my main class where I start the thread:

```
public void addImage(){
            Image I = new Image();
            x = panel.getGraphics();
            I.paint(x);
            Thread thr=new Thread(I);
            thr.start();
        }
```

Comment: Don't call `getGraphics()`. It won't work well and will be overridden once the repaint manager decides to paint. Instead use `paintComponent(Graphics)` and be sure to call super!

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Also, variable names should be meaningful. Why would you use "I", it doesn't follow any of the above guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `paint()` should be

Like this:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    ...
}
```

- Never call `paint()/paintComponent()` directly. Instead call `repaint()`, this adds it to the event queue. The graphics object is passed by swing.
- I'm not sure g.dispose() is necessary, and might cause problems.
- Check the panel your painting into is sized correctly - a quick way to debug this is `panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));`
- Consider using a javax.swing.Timer instead of Thread. This isn't the cause of problem, but would be cleaner.

Comment: I tried what you told me and i corrected my code like this:
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
 
 g.drawImage(image, x, y, this);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
}

and this:
Image i = new Image();
         i.repaint();
         Thread thr=new Thread(i);
         thr.start();
     }
still not working tho.

Comment: Can you simplify to self contained example? Possible problem exists elsewhere in your JPanel subclass or JFrame construction.  Bedtime for me now,  so won't be looking at this until tomorrow.